# Derivative of SVM loss function wrt x

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is the loss function:
$$\text{loss}=\max(0,1−y\ f(x)),$$
where $f(x)$ is [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqVG.png), and the kernel used is the gaussian kernel.
What would then be the derivative of this loss function wrt to the input, $x4?

Comment: One thing to note is that this loss function is not differentiable.